# How to add Electron to Angular-cli project?

Tags: electron, angular-cli

How I can add Electron prebuild to Angular-cli project. I created index.js file inside the src folder which looks like this:

```
var electron = require("electron");
 var {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;

 app.on('ready', () => {
var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();
mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html`);
  });
```

My package.json file for electron app:

```
{
  "name"    : "store-calc",
  "version" : "0.1.0",
  "main"    : "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "electron ."
   }
}
```

Also I changed;  to

However I get this error:

```
{{#unless environment.production}} {{/unless}} Loading... {{#each scripts.polyfills}} {{/each}}
```

Note:**index.js and package for Electron are included inside src folder.**

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron